# Best option for Neo4j 2.3.2+: CentOS 7 or Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: neo4j, installation, ubuntu-14.04, centos7

I will install Neo4j (Community) on a virtual server. Initially 2.3.2, but later perhaps also updated versions. This is both for testing and production uses.

I have the option of choosing either CentOS 7 or Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I would like to know which is the best option regarding ease of installation, lifetime support, maintenance, use, and getting support. The virtual server will not be used for other purposes.

I am aware of the experimental [yum repository](http://yum.neo4j.org/) and the [Debian repository](http://debian.neo4j.org/). Based on this, installation may be easier on Ubuntu, but it is not clear if and how long 14.04 will be supported by this repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian packages for Neo4j (http://debian.neo4j.org/) are not experimental - in contrast to RPM packages. Making these first class citizens as well is on the list.

Based on that I'd go with Ubuntu over CentOs. If you decide for CentOS, I'd prefer the `tar.gz` based artifacts over rpm packages.

The debian packages should be independent of the Ubuntu version you're using.